# MVC Tab postback when clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, tabs

I have browsed the web looking for a solution on this I have three tabs on my page Inbox, Send and Deleted as shown below

```
  <li class="active">
     <a href='@Url.Action("UserEmails", "Profile", routeValues: new { area = "Profile", s = (int)Enums.EmailStatus.Inbox })'>
        <i class="blue ace-icon fa fa-inbox bigger-130"></i>
        <span class="bigger-110">Inbox</span>
     </a>
  </li>
  <li>
     <a href='@Url.Action("UserEmails", "Profile", routeValues: new { area = "Profile", s = (int)Enums.EmailStatus.Sent })'>
        <i class="orange ace-icon fa fa-location-arrow bigger-130"></i>
        <span class="bigger-110">Sent</span>
     </a>
  </li>
  <li>
     <a href='@Url.Action("UserEmails", "Profile", routeValues: new { area = "Profile", s = (int)Enums.EmailStatus.Deleted })'>
        <i class="red ace-icon glyphicon glyphicon-trash bigger-130"></i>
        <span class="bigger-110">Deleted</span>
     </a>
  </li>
```

as you can see I have specified the URL I require it to postback to when its clicked, this is my controller

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult UserEmails(int s) // Called when the view is requested for the first time
    {
        try
        {
            _userEmails = GetUserEmails(s);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }

        return View(_userEmails);
    }
```

Now when I click the tabs it doesn't post back, can someone enlighten me in to why this isn't the case?

Comment: You have only `<a>` tags which redirect to a GET method. If you want to post to `public ActionResult UserEmails(int s)` then you need a `<form>`. But why do you need a POST? You don't seem to be modifying any data so it could be a GET.

Comment: Hi I changed the controller because like you said I'm not manipulating the data, now I only have the get useremails but when I click a tab it doesn't post back still

Comment: Edit your question to show the revised code.

Comment: @StephenMuecke modified.

Comment: Have you put a break point in the GET method to ensure its getting hit

Comment: I've placed a break point on it, clicked on all three tabs and it doesn't postback

Comment: Are you using a jquery plugin? Are you getting any errors in the browser console?

Comment: @StephenMuecke no plugin, just basic HTML and MVC

Comment: @StephenMuecke seems to be this that's causing the issue data-toggle="tab"

Comment: Perhaps, just add `@Html.ActionLink("Inbox", "UserEmails", "Profile", new { area = "Profile", s = 1 }, null)` to test

Comment: `data-toggle="tab"` is what made me think you were using a plugin. What else is it for?

Comment: @StephenMuecke  I have bootstrap linked in to it, but I didn't think that would cause an issue?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have removed the data-toggle and it now posts back without the parameter added, but when I introduce the parameter it doesn't postback?

Comment: Did you try the `@Html.ActionLink`?

Comment: I don't use bootstrap, but I'm fairly sure you misunderstanding the use of tabs. Clicking on the tabs just makes the content of that tab visible, it's not for dynamically loading content by calling an action method. You would need render the content for all 3 tabs in the initial page load (e.g. `@Html.Action(...)` or load the content using ajax.